# How can I find all resources "shared with me" and "owned by me" using Keycloak authzClient?

Tags: java, kotlin, keycloak

On Keycloak I have several resources and I need to fetch all resources owned by me and "**shared with me**" by other users.

For example, this resource is owned by "test" user and it is shared with "test2" user:

[image: Keycloak resources]

[image: Resource shared with test2]

So the idea is test2 will fetch resources shared with him.

But the only option I see is to find by Owner/Name/Uri: [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_protection_resources_apihttps://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_protection_resources_api)

```kotlin
/**
     * Query the server for any resource with the matching arguments.
     *
     * @param id the resource id
     * @param name the resource name
     * @param uri the resource uri
     * @param owner the resource owner
     * @param type the resource type
     * @param scope the resource scope
     * @param matchingUri the resource uri. Use this parameter to lookup a resource that best match the given uri
     * @param exactName if the the {@code name} provided should have a exact match   
     * @param deep if the result should be a list of resource representations with details about the resource. If false, only ids are returned
     * @param firstResult the position of the first resource to retrieve
     * @param maxResult the maximum number of resources to retrieve
     * @return a list of resource representations or an array of strings representing resource ids, depending on the generic type
     */
    public <R> R find(final String id, final String name, final String uri, final String owner, final String type, final String scope, final boolean matchingUri, final boolean exactName, final boolean deep, final Integer firstResult, final Integer maxResult)
```

By other side, the keycloak account UI application seems to call to an
[endpoint to fetch the resources shared-with-me](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/e56bd9d8b8cbaf4600e6bcc5e28c962eb561d74c/themes/src/main/resources/theme/keycloak.v2/account/src/app/content/my-resources-page/MyResourcesPage.tsx#L97)

Comment: What do you mean be resources

Comment: I have just uploaded several screen shots.

Comment: Thanks, for that.

Comment: Just for curiosity when you go to the users' "My resources" page what rest calls is keycloak on the back, any interesting get?

Comment: Not really because the "My resource" tab calls to `http://localhost/auth/realms/<realm>/account/resource?referrer=<client_id>`
but this is just the UI that returns the text/html page. The REST API endpoint that returns the same simila info is this other: `http://localhost/auth/realms/<realm>/authz/protection/resource_set`, but I just only achieve it returns the resources owned by yourself, not the shared with you.

Comment: Yep, you are right from there nothing too useful came out.

Comment: I found Keycloak has an endpoint: `/resources/shared-with-me` but it returns me the error: `"error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost/auth/realms/<realm>/account/resources/shared-with-me"`

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bb7ce62cd51180bb1117dda6978f258c3c5269ce/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/account/resources/ResourcesService.java

Comment: Probably, it should be called in a different context. From the outside looking in I would expected some more information at least the userID

Answer (score 1):

If you send an empty authorization request to Keycloak then it returns all allowed permissions with the associated resources. This list includes owned by you or sharing with you.

```kotlin
fun AuthzClient.findAllGrantedPermissions(accessToken: String): TokenIntrospectionResponse {
    val request = AuthorizationRequest()
    val rpt = this.authorization(accessToken).authorize(request).token
    return this.protection().introspectRequestingPartyToken(rpt)
}
```